# CreateCriteria Grails inside a hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain in Grails that is `Case` and other that is `Payment`.

I want to obtain the `Case`s that all `Payment`s that is in the payments List( That is contained on the `hasMany` relationship), has the same `collectorNick`.

Example:

```
payment1 (collectorNick:a)  
payment2 (collectorNick:a) 
payment3 (collectorNick:b) 


Case1(payments[payment1,payment2]
Case2(payments[payment1,payment3]
```

When search for `collectorNick:a` the result will be Case1 because both payment `collectorNick` is a and Case2 has payment3 and the collector of payment3 is `b`.

I have tried to achieve that, but when the `createCriteria` that I have created I obtain both Case1 and Case2

I know that can be done in different ways, but I need to do with `createCriteria` from `Case`, because I need later to filter from some other fields of cases.

`Case` has

```
List<Payment> payments
static hasMany = [ payments: Payment ]
```

and `Payment` has

```
String collectorNick
```

And the `createCriteria` that I use is:

```
 def cases = Case.createCriteria().list(max: limit, offset: offset){ 
               and{  
                   payments { 
                           eq('collectorNick', params.collector)
                   }
               }
             }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do (find only `Case` instances where **all** payments were collected by a given collector), how about:

```
def cases = Case.createCriteria().list(max: limit, offset: offset){
    not {
        payments {
                ne('collectorNick', params.collector)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why the double negation?